# Re-throwing exceptions are not caught

Tags: php, exception

I'm building a custom exception class to manage all exceptions:

```
class MyExceptions extends Exception
{
    public function __construct($message = 'Unkown errror', $code = -1, Exception $previous = null) {
        echo 'init!';
        parent::__construct($message, $code, $previous);
    }   
}
```

Now, when a PDOException occurs, I want to re-throw it to MyExceptions:

```
class myDB
{
    private $db;

    public function dbConnect() {
        try {
            $this->db = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=db;charset=utf8', 'user', 'pass');
        }
        catch (PDOException $e) {
            throw new MyExceptions($e);
        }
        /* Updated */
        catch (MyExceptions $e) {
            echo 'caught!';             
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is that when a db connection exception rises, I get the following fatal error on screen:

```
init!
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'MyExceptions' with message...
```

So, the exception is not caught, although the MyExceptions __construct() is called (see the 'init!' displayed).
Every bit of resource I read points to the exact implementation as mine, I have no idea what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: Do you capture the rethrown exception as well?

Comment: If it shows "with message ....", what happens when you call Exception::getMessage() on it?

Comment: `catch` blocks only catch exceptions for what's inside the preceding `try` block. You cannot catch exceptions thrown from a `catch` block with a sibling `catch` block. Instead, you have to nest it inside another `try`/`catch` sequence.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need

```
try {
   try {
      $this->db = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=db;charset=utf8', 'user', 'pass');
   } catch (PDOException $e) {
        throw new MyExceptions($e);
   }
} catch (MyExceptions $f) {
    echo 'caught!';             
}
```

Sequential catch blocks are for different types of exceptions thrown within the try.

Comment: Ok, got it now! I was under the wrong impression that sibling catch blocks can throw exceptions from one to the other. Thanks Philip!

Comment: @Stingus: No, not at all. But now I understood why you asked. You might have looked for goto instead of exceptions in that case.

Answer (score 1):

You are throwing it:

```
throw new MyExceptions($e);
^^^^^
```

And then you don't catch it. So what do you wonder about?

Also you should add the previous exception at third position (for previous) instead of the first position (for message).

Comment: Actually, I had a `catch (MyExceptions $e)` block before I copy / pasted the code. I will edit the question with it now.

Comment: If you'll have a look at the code now the `MyExceptions catch` is there. I also updated `throw new MyExceptions('message', 0, $e)`. Now I have `Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message...`

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't go through all the catch blocks. Only the first one that matches. If you then throw another exception inside a catch block, you'd have to catch it in another try block around the first one.